# laravel mongodb belongstomany with custom relationship name not working?

Tags: laravel, mongodb

Using Laravel v10 and [MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

**Note**: the below describes the MongoDB specific implementation of [belongsToMany](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#belongstomany-and-pivots).

I have e.g. Author and Book. Many to many relationship between Author and Book.
Author contains `id` of the author, but also a `user_id`.
For some reason the (legacy) data has Books using `user_id` to identify the author. I can not use `id` of the Author.

Having trouble adding `user_id` to a Book.
The following returns `null`:

```
$book->authors()->attach($userIds);
```

```php
# Book.php

    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Author::class, null, 'book_ids', 'user_ids'
            # also tried with adding parameter: relatedKey: 'user_id' (default is: 'id')
        );
    }
```

```php
# Author.php

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Book::class, null, 'user_ids', 'book_ids'
        )
    }
```

Not an issue when the relationship is straightforward, i.e. a book has `author_ids`.

Suggestions?

BTW the title says custom relationship name, that should probably be custom key.

Comment: You are specifying wrong keys in the relationship. `book_ids` and `user_ids`?

Comment: You could just update this legacy data with a simple database query

Comment: what do you mean with wrong keys?

Comment: Do you actually have those keys in your pivot table? Are you not using the standard naming convention?

Comment: I can not replace the `user_ids` with `author_ids`.

Comment: Mongodb does not use a pivot table. When you attach related items, that relationship is stored in both objects. I.e. $book gets array of `user_ids` added and the related `authors` each get book ID added to `book_ids` (and it is created if necessary)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254855/discussion-between-wivku-and-miken32).

Comment: Sorry, I have no familiarity with that database, I just assumed a many-to-many relationship would use the same structure regardless of database.